How to do average percentage based on two samples of three variables?
I have data like this



case
total_paths
prev_val
new_val




1
14
0
14


2
20
0
9



I need to calculate the percentage increment in the new value in average based on these two cases. For example, for case 1, percentege increase is (14-0)/14 * 100 = 100%. For case 2, it is (9-0)/20 * 100% = 45%. Is averaging these two percentages (45% and 100%) a good way?
